# Using "will" after "if" in order to make a polite request

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, tense

I've read somewhere that the "if + will" construction may be used to formulate a polite request but I can't recall the exact way as to how to use it correctly.

I've tried to find solutions on the web but I wasn't successful.
Could someone please clarify this for me or point me to an article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that "will" can sometimes be used after "if." However, if you are asking someone to do something, you are likely to use "will" in a question (without using "if" at all). Such questions sound quite polite. For example:

> Will you join me for a drink?
>
> Will you stay for dinner?

We can use "will" after "if" if "will" means "wish,” "want," "desire":

> You may call me John **if you will** (= if you want to).

But there is a phrase which I think you are asking for. The phrase is "if you will." It is said when politely asking someone to do or consider something. Here is how we use it:

> Imagine, **if you will**, a typical silversmith's shop (= please imagine a typical silversmith's shop).

Note that the phrase "if you will" has another meaning too:

> I did very well in school , with a "genius IQ" **if you will**. (this is one way of saying this; if you like)

Comment: Your response has cleared up all my doubts. Thank you.

Comment: It's important to cite your [sources](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/if_you_will), not only because it's proper to acknowledge the original authorship (and, implicitly, the work put into publishing it), but also because failing to do so can make it look like you're claiming their words as your own, which might lead to an accusation of **plagiarism**, [if you will](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/if-you-will).